# In candlestick graph how to set edge color as colorup and colordown using matplotlib library python

Tags: python

```
def candlestric_graph(self, data):

    x=date2num([datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y/%m/%d').date() for d in data['date']])

    candle_trace = zip(x, data['open'], data['high'], data['low'], data['close'], data['volume'])
    ls, rs= candlestick(self.axes, candle_trace, width=.6 ,colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f');
    can=set(candle_trace)

    for r in rs:

        r.set_edgecolor( 'r')
        r.set_linewidth(1.)

    xt = self.axes.get_xticks()
    new_xticks = [datetime.date.isoformat(num2date(d)) for d in xt]
    self.axes.set_xticklabels(new_xticks, rotation=15, horizontalalignment='right')[*enter image description here*][1]
```

My code image looks like the screenshot below. I want to set colorup body edge color as colorup color and colordown body edge color as colordown color:

[image]